# Detect when finger, UIButton, and UIImageView are overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I am using this code to detect when `UIButton` and `UIImageView` are overlapping:

```
CGPoint fingerPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:imageA.superview];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageA.frame, fingerPoint)) {
        NSLog(@"Do something");
    }
```

The code works fine, but I have images B, C, D, E.
How can I loop over a collection of them and move `CGRectContainsPoint()` into the body of that loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* images = @[ imageA, imageB, imageC, imageD, imageE ];
for (UIImageView* image in images) {
    CGPoint fingerPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender locationInView:[image superview]];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(image.frame, fingerPoint)) {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: works, but every image does a different thing so I can't use this

Comment: If you need a different behavior for each image, you have options.  You could subclass UIImageView and add a `doSomething` method.  You could create a protocol and delegate to some outer object.  You could pass in five blocks.  There's not much more we can do for you without more details.